# How to get list of "Collection Level Security Groups" in TFS 201X Api (SDK)

Tags: tfs

I am developing a utility, and I need to retrieve list of Collection Level Security Groups,

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(projectUri));
        IGroupSecurityService gss = projectCollection.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();
```

in `IGroupSecurityService`  there is a `ListApplicationGroups(projectUri)` method which returns security groups with in that project, but I need groups on team project collection,

I can't make a sql query over TFS database and also I don't want to use TFS command line tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved by passing `null` to `ListApplicationGroups(null)`